# text classification using graphs in natural language processing

Tags: graph, nlp, classification, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I tried to search but couldn't find much helpful information regarding this topic. That's why I am asking it here...

I know there are various methods to classify texts (like Logistic regression etc.) and also we have neural network.

But, I was wondering if it is possible to 'classify the texts into multiple classes' using graph theory?
If yes, how should I proceed? Please guide me.

Example:

I like jeansp                    -pos

I like toyota                    -pos

I it so-so place                 -neutral

I hated that trip                -neg

I love that shirt                -pos

that place was horrible          -neg

I liked food but service was bad -neutral

Answer (score 0):

Assume each document is a node, and each word is also a node. Documents have edges to words.

Now, some of your documents have labels and some don't.

You can use graph convolutional networks (GCN) to classify the unlabelled documents.

Take a look at the Python Geometric package that has implemented different versions of graph conovlutional networks. Create your input in a way that Python Geometric accepts, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you, I will use it and let you know if I get success.